# Countif index match to find how many unique values are equal to zero

Tags: excel, countif

I have a excel sheets that looks like something like this

ID |Generation |STNAME

BW1    | 0       |  Main1

BW2   | 2    |     Main1

BW3   | 0      |   Main1

BW4   | 1       |  Main1

GH1   | 0    |     JHkl

GH2   | 0   |      JHkl

GH3   | 4      |   JHkl

GH4   | 0       |  JHkl

I need to find how many times the column STNAME his less than zero

Main1 | 2

JHK1  | 2

I have been trying to use the index match approach by creating another column and using countifs functions but it doesnt seem to find the correct number of values.
I am trying to use the same approach as the link

Click [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/countifs-with-variable-table-column)!

Comment: **less than** zero or **equal to** zero ???

Comment: so this is just a sample table and i have just posted a snapshot i need to find how many are equal to zero and how many are greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use the [COUNTIFS](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) function.

Assuming the data structure above where C2:C9 is the values of the column "STNAME":

If you want to know how many are equal to 0, use:

=COUNTIFS(C2:C9,"Main1",B2:B9,0)

If you want to know how many are greater or equal to 0, use:

=COUNTIFS(C2:C9,"Main1",B2:B9,">=0")